# Writing H264 File using Microsoft sample Dump Filter

Tags: directshow, h.264, mpeg-4

I just create  a simple Graph

```
Source Filter [ MPEG4 || H264 ] ----> DumpFilter
```

I can write raw encoded video stream to file  and can play.

But there is a problem with H264 video. When i play recorded H264 stream it play too fast.(Should have to play 0.65x speed). [ MPEG4 video stteam plays at its right speed/fps].

Why this happens and how can i fix it?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this graph you don't use any container with a header, and information about FPS is usually stored in a header. Without it the splitter doesn't know proper values and inserts some made up ones.